# Classic ASP Focus Textbox Forever/Never Lose Focus

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to focus a textbox, and even if they click somewhere else on the screen, continue to keep this textbox as focused?

Comment: The answer to this involves client side code, most likely Javascript.  It's not an asp question, even if the site uses Classic ASP elsewhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why you would ever want to do this, as I personally would leave the site if a page on the site did this. I like to have control over my browser thank you very much :)

This is how you could pull it off though:

```
<input type="text" onblur="this.focus()" />
```

Comment: I am doing it as a MES system.  A hidden textbox that allows them to continously scan, even if the touch screen they are using clicks somewhere by random! :)